# lwjgl and slick - rotate slick texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I am creating a program which draws an object, which needs to "point" toward the mouse.  To do so I want to draw the image rotated.

I have this code for drawing the object:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,img.getTextureID());
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0,0);
glVertex2f(x-r,y-r);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);
glVertex2f(x+r,y-r);
glTexCoord2f(1,1);
glVertex2f(x+r,y+r);
glTexCoord2f(0,1);
glVertex2f(x-r,y+r);
glEnd();
```

Pretty basic.  But I was having a hard time finding out how to rotate the texture, or draw the texture rotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on @genpfault's answer:

If you want your texture to rotate around its center, you need to draw it so its center is at (0,0).  Try something like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y); // move to the proper position
glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 ); // now rotate

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,img.getTextureID());
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0,0);
glVertex2f(-r,-r);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);
glVertex2f(+r,-r);
glTexCoord2f(1,1);
glVertex2f(+r,+r);
glTexCoord2f(0,1);
glVertex2f(-r,+r);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix(); // pop off the rotation and transformation
```

Note that `glRotatef`'s angle is in degrees, not radians.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the texture:

```
glMatrixMode( GL_TEXTURE );
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
drawTexturedQuad();
```

Rotating the quad:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );
drawTexturedQuad();
glPopMatrix();
```